# $f$ is a function so that $f(ab + 1) = af(b) − f(a) + 6$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

If a function $f$ exists so that $f(ab + 1) = af(b) − f(a) + 6$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$. What are all possible functions $f$ that satisfy this equation and also prove that there are no other functional solutions that make the equation true? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $b =0$ to get $f(1)=af(0)-f(a)+6$. Solve this for $f(a)$.

You get $f(x)=cx+d$ for  some $c$ and $d$. Now go back to the original equation to see what you can say about $c$ and $d$.

The answer is $f(x)=2x+2$.

Comment: how do you prove that there are no other functions that satisfy the equation?

Comment: @joeken When you put $f(x)=cx+d$ in the given equation the terms in  $ab$ cancel out. You will only have terms in $a$ , $b$ and a constant term. Since this equation is valid for all $a$ and $b$ the coefficients of $a$ and $b$ on the two side have to be the same. From this you can easily see that $c=d=2$.

Answer (score 1):

After Kabo Murphy's "put $b=0$"step, put $a = 0$ and find $f(1) = -f(0) + 6$, allowing you to eliminate $f(1)$ from the two equations, giving $f(a)$ in terms of $f(0)$.

Then put $a = b = 1$ to discover the value of $f(2)$.  Use this in your relation $f(a) = \text{[constant expression containing $f(0)$]}$ to find a formula for $f(a)$ in terms of $a$ and constants.

Comment: how do you prove that there are no other functions that satisfy the equation? How is f(a) = 2a+2 the only equation using your method?

Comment: @joeken : When did we put in a choice?  The functional equation forces $f(1) = 6 - f(0)$, true for any solution. The functional equation forces $f(1) = af(0) − f(a) + 6$, true for any solution.  Elimination forces $f(a) = (1+a)f(0)$, true for any solution.  The functional equation forces $f(2) = 6$, true for any solution.  With the result of elimination, $f(2) = 3 f(0)$, we are forced to conclude $f(0) = 2$, true for any solution.  All of this was forced upon us, so *every* solution is $f(a) = (1+a)\cdot 2$.